# SuiteScript 2.0 - How to get string from UserEventType

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

The following code creates a log entry with details: UserEventType: [object Object], Internal id: 11.

```
define(['N/log'], function (log)
{    
    function afterSubmit(context)
    {
        log.debug({
            title: 'afterSubmit',
            details: 'UserEventType: ' + context.UserEventType + ', Internal id: ' + context.newRecord.id
        });
    }
});
```

How can I get a meaningful string from context.UserEventType ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[context.UserEventType](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4407992596.html) is an Object.

So, to get complete log details you can either use

```
log.debug({
  title: 'afterSubmit',
  details: 'UserEventType: ' + JSON.stringify(context.UserEventType) + ', Internal id: ' + context.newRecord.id
});
```

or

```
log.debug({
  title: 'afterSubmit',
  details: {
    'UserEventType': context.UserEventType,
    'Internal id': context.newRecord.id
  }
});
```